# Concatenate variable + string inside of a Join(Array())

Tags: vbscript, string-concatenation

I have the script below that make a referer to two files names and the second file name is present inside a `Join(Array())` between `""`, but I'm needing use a folder name that already was defined before in a variable, for create a new file inside this folder and that will store the final result produced by this script:

```
    Option Explicit

Const LOCAL_APPLICATION_DATA = &H1c&

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(LOCAL_APPLICATION_DATA)
Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self

Set colItems = objFolder.Items

Dim sCurDir
Dim sFina

For Each objItem in colItems

    If InStr(1, objItem.Name, "Google") > 0 Then

      sCurDir =  objFolderItem.Path + "\" + objItem.Name + "\Chrome\User Data\Default\"
      sFina = "History"

      Exit For

    End If
Next

    Function qq(s) : qq = """" & s & """" : End Function

    Const cnHidden = 0
    Const cbWait = True

    Dim sCmd : sCmd = Join(Array( _
         "%comspec%" _
       , "/c" _
       , "sqlite3.exe" _
       , "-csv" _
       , qq("..\data\History") _
       , qq("SELECT id, url FROM urls LIMIT 5") _
       , ">.\urls.csv" _
    ))
    WScript.Echo sCmd
    CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run sCmd, cnHidden, cbWait
    WScript.Echo "Done"
```

Then, if I try replace `">.\urls.csv"` by for example `""""+sCurDir + "new.csv"""` the file don't is created. How solve it?

Comment: What is output of this line? WScript.Echo sCmd

Comment: `Dim sCmd : sCmd = Join(Array( _
         "%comspec%" _
       , "/c" _
       , "sqlite3.exe" _
       , "-csv" _
       , qq(sCurDir + sFina) _
       , qq("SELECT id, url FROM urls LIMIT 5") _
       , ">.\urls.csv" _
    ))`

Comment: @AlexGawkins, after replace `">.\urls.csv"` by for example `""""+sCurDir + "new.csv"""`, the result of query command is [this](http://i.imgur.com/ksDhYct.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Solved:***

```
    Dim strUser
    strUser = CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserName

    ...

    Dim sCmd : sCmd = Join(Array( _
             "%comspec%" _
           , "/c" _
           , "sqlite3.exe" _
           , "-csv" _
           , qq(sCurDir + sFina) _
           , qq("SELECT url FROM urls") _
           , ">C:\Users\"+strUser+"\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\new.csv" _
        ))
```